# Flatlist vs map callback columns in React native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to show a bunch of images in rows of 3 images and using Flatlist i got this error "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component". I tried everything about using an unmount flag but the problem still persists.

However, noticed that with the map() callback function that problem doesn't exist. **The problem is how to create A View with map() in order to render 3 images at each row.** Is there a possible way to create a View with 3 columns using map()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your problem is "The problem is how to create A View with map() in order to render 3 images at each row." then i'll answer your question with a .map() answer instead of a flatlist answer.

For .map() it will render as many images as there are in the array that you've called .map on. The spacing in that scenario is moreso done by the container you've wrapped it in, plus you can give each image a width of '33%'. Meaning, you'll want something like this:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
    {YOURARRAY.map(() => {
      return(
        ---- your image with the style {width: '33%'} here ----
    )}
<View>
```